# SQL self-joins Help Query

Tags: mysql

How to display those employees who are working in the same dept where his manager in the below table:

[image]

?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `self join` will do.

```
select e1.*
from emp e1 inner join emp e2 
    on e1.mgr = e2.eno
where e1.dept_no = e2.dept_no
```